# IIS re-processing the same request during 504 (Gateway timeout) on AWS (Amazon)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, amazon-web-services, iis-7, amazon-elb

The setup is as follows =>

There is an Amazon ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) that forwards requests to IIS. The ELB has a time out setting of 15 seconds.

If the web server takes more that 15 seconds to process a request, I observe two behaviors.

1) Sometimes, at the 15 second mark, a 504 (Gateway Timeout) is issued to the client (browser). This behavior I understand and is expected.

2) However, sometimes, at the 15 second mark, the web server (IIS) begins to re-process the same request again from the beginning. There is no 504 (Gateway Timeout) issued to the client. This behavior, I don't understand. I use ASP.NET MVC stack.

I know its the same request from the client because the client generated id stays same for the request. But there is a new server generated id for the request. Some the intermediary (ELB) seems to be reforwarding the request at the timeout (15 second) mark in some cases.

Does anyone have insights on what could be causing (2) ?

Comment: Are you sure the user isn't getting impatient and pressing F5 and resubmitting the request?  It's hard to tell from your description if the "unique request id" would stay the same or not in this case.

Comment: I don't see how the process could be starting over from the beginning.  If it was, wouldn't it assign a new request id?  If not, then it's not actually starting at the beginning and you should see where it is actually starting at.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Digging further I have found that the client generated request id does not change but the server generated request id does CHANGE! So somehow ELB is reforwarding the same request sometimes at the 15 second mark. Does it make any sense?

Comment: I doubt that.. I think it's more likely that the user is pressing F5, unless it's an ajax request... F5 would cause the same request to be resubmitted with the same client generated ID.

Comment: No its not the user pressing F5. I verified myself by making a request from the REST client. It sounds strange, but that seems to be the behavior of the intermediary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're dealing with this issue:

http://absenceofblue.blogspot.com/2013/08/retry-hassles-with-elb.html

Supposedly it was fixed, but apparently if your backend timeout is the same as the ELB timeout there can be a race condition, so you should set your timeout to at least 1 second greater than the ELB timeout so that ELB dumps the connection, and not your code.

The interesting thing about this is that the retry DOES in fact originate from the client, but it's because the client's TCP stack is fooled into thinking the packet was dropped so it retries the packet at the TCP level.